# NSData and NSString conversion not equal

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

So I got an NSData object from network, like:

> <93000000 026d6163 69640029 00000032 66353637 32636237 36363931 62393839 62626432 30323261 35333439 39333961 32643762 39353200 02696661 00210000 00373138 38616134 30313532 35346437 63396162 65326262 62326361 65653762 39000269 66760021 00000061 30346635 30373862 63383034 34343362 64636431 37653666 34326539 38306300 0a757569 640000>

Now I want to see what's the string using encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding:

`[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]`

and I get:

> "\xc2\x93\0\0\0\x02macid\0)\0\0\02f5672cb76691b989bbd2022a5349939a2d7b952\0\x02ifa\0!\0\0\07188aa4015254d7c9abe2bbb2caee7b9\0\x02ifv\0!\0\0\0a04f5078bc804443bdcd17e6f42e980c\0\nuuid\0\0"

Note: This string makes sense to me, because

> a04f5078bc804443bdcd17e6f42e980c

is my device identifier get from

`[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor]`

Now I want to convert it back to NSData:

`[str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]`

> <13000000 026d6163 69640029 00000032 66353637 32636237 36363931 62393839 62626432 30323261 35333439 39333961 32643762 39353200 02696661 00210000 00373138 38616134 30313532 35346437 63396162 65326262 62326361 65653762 39000269 66760021 00000061 30346635 30373862 63383034 34343362 64636431 37653666 34326539 38306300 0a757569 640000>

As you can see, the first section is changed. How do I keep it the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x93` is beyond the ASCII range, use a text encoding which also considers values > `0x7F` for example `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding`

Comment: I think it's still a string, because a04f5078bc804443bdcd17e6f42e980c is my device identifier, so I think it makes sense

Comment: how do I know the encoding?

Comment: @Wingzero If it's not an issue about the encoding, it could be an issue on how you get the `NSData` object in the first place.

Comment: The first byte in the `NSData` object is `0x93` but ASCII is only 7 bit (0x00 - 0x7F) and `0x93` without the most significant bit is `0x13`.

Comment: @Droppy why you say so? I got no knowledge of encoding, but vadian explained to me and it does work.

Comment: [Here's its definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) and a `NUL` is a `NUL` and your data contains `NUL`.  It's not even a string I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid string (it contains `NUL` characters, for example):

```
@"\xc2\x93\0\0\0\x02macid\0)\0\0\02f5672cb76691b989bbd2022a5349939a2d7b952\0\x02ifa\0!\0\0\07188aa4015254d7c9abe2bbb2caee7b9\0\x02ifv\0!\0\0\0a04f5078bc804443bdcd17e6f42e980c\0\nuuid\0\0"
```

So it's clear that the data is not using ASCII encoding, or possibly it's not even an encoded string in the first place.  In order to get the correct string you need to know its encoding (this is often provided as meta-data from web servers, for example).  Once you know the correct encoding, you can produce a valid string and then generate other encodings from that string.

Comment: I think it's still a string, because a04f5078bc804443bdcd17e6f42e980c is my device identifier, so I think it makes sense

Comment: how do I know the encoding?

Comment: Just because you can recognise strings in the data doesn't mean the whole data is a string. You should be told the encoding when the string is sent to you.

Comment: thanks. I don't know the encoding, I just got the NSData object from network. The question is more like, how can I guess the encoding

Comment: It's not a string, so there is no encoding.